Assigning value is atomic/thread safe?
using ConsoleApp1;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

Vector3 v1;

int n = 1000000000;

var t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        v1 = new Vector3(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
    }
}));

var t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        v1 = new Vector3(2.0F, 2.0F, 2.0F);
    }
}));

var t3 = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        v1 = new Vector3(3.0F, 3.0F, 3.0F);
    }
}));

t1.Start();
t2.Start();
t3.Start();

t1.Join();
t2.Join();
t3.Join();

In above, Assigning value is atomic/thread-safe?
The order doesn't matter whether new Vector3(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F), new Vector3(2.0F, 2.0F, 2.0F), or new Vector3(3.0F, 3.0F, 3.0F) was assigned.
But i wonder the value v1 will be overlapped, like (1.0F, 3.0F, 2.0F).
If it is atomic/thread-safe, why?
The execution result is that the value is not overlapped.
I think it is related to memory writing.
The thread write the value to memory with some length and the other thread cannot write the value to that memory simultaneosuly.
Is it correct?

I think it is related to luck.  There's nothing in that code to enforce the order of operations.

Each new Vector3(...) statement creates a new Vector3 object in the heap. After the object is created, it is assigned to v1. The race condition between the threads is only on the assignment to v1. The code will never produce a Vector3 instance with (1.0F, 3.0F, 2.0F) because such an object is never newed.

@JonathanDodds Vector3 is a struct and a field here, so I think struct tearing is possible

Might be a stackoverflow duplicate of this

seems like it can happen. Unity, which relies massively on Vector3, also seem to have atomic safety module for such cases. It depends on your use case, but I'd suggest reconsider about this pattern before you proceeds.

Since Vector3 is a struct with 3 float fields, this means that the size of the vector would be 3*32 = 96bits which might present the Struct tearing issue for most processors

Struct tearing is a threading issue that affects all structs larger
than what can be atomically updated on the target processor
architecture. For example, some 64-bit processors can only update one
64-bit aligned memory block atomically.

A similar question has been asked with regard to DateTime and not Vector3, you'd be well off checking the answers there as well.
The following code that builds on your test example demonstrates that struct tearing is indeed an issue with Vector3 (at least on my old 64bit laptop):
static void Main() {
    int tries = 4_000_000;
    var threadCount = 2; // if more than two the tear can be "repaired" with future overwrites

    Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);

    var listTears = new List<Vector3>();

    Action<Barrier> postPhase = _ => {
        if (!(v1.X == v1.Y && v1.Y == v1.Z)) {
            var capture = v1;
            listTears.Add(capture);
        }
        v1=default; // reset for next race
    };

    var barrier = new Barrier(threadCount, postPhase);
    var listOfThreads = new List<Thread>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= threadCount; i++) {
        var capturedThreadId = i;
        var t1 = new Thread(() => {
            for (int j = 0; j < tries; j++) {
                v1 = new Vector3(capturedThreadId, capturedThreadId, capturedThreadId);
                barrier.SignalAndWait();
            }
        });
        listOfThreads.Add(t1);
    }

    foreach (var element in listOfThreads) {
        element.Start();
    }

    foreach (var element in listOfThreads) {
        element.Join();
    }

    var countTears = listTears.Count;
    var countTearsXtoY = listTears.Where(vector => vector.X != vector.Y).Count();
    Console.WriteLine($"Struct tears -> not (v1.X==v1.Y==v1.Z) : {countTears}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Count not (v1.X==v1.Y): {countTearsXtoY}"); // 0


    var takeTenTears = listTears.Take(10);
    foreach (var element in takeTenTears) {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}

I normally get around 100-1000 tears from 4_000_000 trials, e.g:
Struct tears -> not (v1.X==v1.Y==v1.Z) : 309
Count not (v1.X==v1.Y): 0 
<2, 2, 1>
<1, 1, 2>
<1, 1, 2>
<2, 2, 1>
<2, 2, 1>
<2, 2, 1>
<2, 2, 1>
<1, 1, 2>
<1, 1, 2>
<1, 1, 2>

The interesting thing is that the tear happens to the value of v1.Z. v1.X is always equal to v1.Y which makes sense since those two are the first 64bits of the struct which can be and in my case are always updated atomically.
